# Change text field editing in GNOME 3 to use Control and Meta keys like Emacs or bash

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, keyboard, text, widgets

A while ago I did [this](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/Site/cocoa-text.html) on my Mac and I was able to use Emacs controls in all Cocoa Text Widgets. I'm a big Emacs user and it's really been great to do such lightning fast editing in email and web text widgets. I did that by adding some key macros to a file. Is there any way to do this in GNOME? I'd really like to be able to use C-n-p-f-b-a-e and M-f-b. M-> and M-< would be a plus too. I don't really know much about GNOME, but I figured there might be a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Found these in some forum posts; does either work for you?

```
gconftool-2 --set /desktop/gnome/interface/gtk_key_theme Emacs --type string

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-key-theme Emacs
```