# Enable global terminal movement keys

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys

In terminal I can use:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> → Backspace

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> → Return (Enter)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> → Forward

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> → Backward

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> → Next

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> → Previous

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> → Beginning of line (Home)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> → End of line (End)

And I would like to have these shortcuts work globally. So for instance I could use them while writing and editing this question!

I have had a look around the internet and it seems that I should be using xmodmap for this. However I can't work out how to map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key events. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Key</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Key</kbd> events seem straight forward enough, but I can't work out how to incorporate <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

Comment: Does the suggestion in this older question work for you?

http://askubuntu.com/questions/139945/change-text-field-editing-in-gnome-3-to-use-control-and-meta-keys-like-emacs-or

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using **Tweak Tool**:

[image: Tweak Tool]
<sub>(source: [ubuntu.com](https://apps.ubuntu.com/assets/images/scbutton-free-200px.png))</sub>

Go to **Theme** tab and change **Gtk + Keybinding Theme** to **Emacs**:

[image: Gtk + Keybinding Theme to Emacs]

Comment: Thanks, I found this before but emacs doesn't use Ctrl+h for backspace which is actually important to me

Comment: @Anake Just try it, `Ctrl+h` it's working like a charm. Even here!

Comment: Sorry to have doubted you, thank you very much!